# How do I parse the properties of a json object into a map using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, yaml

I would like to read the properties of a YAML object into a Map, without knowing ahead of time what the map keys will be.

My class:

```
    final static String mapExample =
                    "abc: 1\n" +
                    "def: 20\n";

    @Data
    static class MapTestClass {
        Map<String, Integer> answers;
    }

    @Test
    public void mapTest() throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        MapTestClass mapTestClass = mapper.readValue(mapExample, MapTestClass.class);
    }
```

What I would like is for my Java Map to be populated with the two obvious entries.  But when I run this test I get an UnrecognizedPropertyException:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "abc" (class com.ciscospark.federationmigrationorchestrator.FmdTest$MapTestClass), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "answers"])
```

Is there a simple way to do this?  I would like to avoid using ObjectMapper.readTree() because I do want the mapper to populate the data into a well-defined class (this example is excerpted from a much more complicated structure).

Comment: `mapExample ` doesn't contain a valid json value so how should that be parsed successfully? For parsing maps there are several ways, one would be `readTree()` which basically returns a hierarchy of maps and lists but you could also use a `TypeReference<Map<String, Integer>>` or parse `MapTestClass` and annotate `answers` appropriately (e.g. with `@JsonAnyGetter` etc. - if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I'm using Jackson in this case to parse a YAML document. Notice that the ObjectMapper is constructed using a `YAMLFactory()`.  But I believe the question applies equally well if I were to parse a JSON document.

The `TypeReference` suggestion worked for me - thanks!

Comment: Oh yes, missed that `YAMLFactory()` - my bad. Glad it worked though :)